# online quiz Question id not insert in to database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hey Guys i am new here anyone help me ...my problem is that i am working on a online quiz exam with php and ajax ..problem is that i am inserting Question ID into database so anyone help me solve this problem ...i show you my codes..

```js
                     <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){  
           var stu_ans=$(this).val();  
          var stu_id ="<?php echo $_GET['sid'];?>"; 
   var q_id = $('#qname').val();
           $.ajax({  
                url:"insert1.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{stu_ans:stu_ans, stu_id:stu_id,q_id:q_id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
  
  <script>
  $('.cont').addClass('hide');

  $('#question_splitter_1').removeClass('hide');
   
  $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
      last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));  console.log( last );   
      nex=last+1;
      $('#question_splitter_'+last).addClass('hide');
      
      $('#question_splitter_'+nex).removeClass('hide');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
      last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
      pre=last-1;
      $('#question_splitter_'+last).addClass('hide');
      
      $('#question_splitter_'+pre).removeClass('hide');
  });
            
      
  </script>
```

```css
      <style>
input[type="radio"] {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
  </style>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluied">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    
    <hr>
    <form  role="form" id='formid' method="post" action="result.php?s_id=<?php echo $_GET['sid'];?>">
     <?php
     $number_question = 1;
     $row = mysqli_query( $con, "select * from question where subject_id='$category' ORDER BY RAND()");
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows( $row );
     $remainder = $rowcount/$number_question;
     $i = 0;
     $j = 1; $k = 1;
     
     ?>
     <h4>Total Question:-<?php echo $rowcount;?></h4>
     <?php while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row) ) {
       if ( $i == 0) echo "<div class='cont' id='question_splitter_$j'>";?>
      <div id='question<?php echo $k;?>' >
      <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $j;?>" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:green"> (<?php echo $k?>).<?php echo $result['que'];?></p>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result['que'];?>" name="qname<?php echo $j;?>" id="qname">
      <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table">

<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>

<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

      <tr>
         <td>(A)<?php echo trim($result['o1']);?></td>
        <td colspan="5"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['o1'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'></td>
       
      </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>(B)<?php echo $result['o2'];?>
     </td>
   <td colspan="5"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['o2'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/></td>
  
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>(C)<?php echo $result['o3'];?></td>
   <td colspan="5"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['o3'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
      </td>
 
   </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>(D)<?php echo $result['o4'];?></td>
   <td colspan="5"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['o4'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
      </td>

   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
     
     
      
      
      
      <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
      <br/>
      </div>
      <?php
        $i++; 
        if ( ( $remainder < 1 ) || ( $i == $number_question && $remainder == 1 ) ) {
         echo "<button id='".$j."' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>";
         echo "</div>";
        }  elseif ( $rowcount > $number_question  ) {
         if ( $j == 1 && $i == $number_question ) {
         echo "<button id='".$j."' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>";
         echo "</div>";
         $i = 0;
         $j++;           
        } elseif ( $k == $rowcount ) { 
         echo " <button id='".$j."' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>
            <button id='".$j."' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>";
         echo "</div>";
         $i = 0;
         $j++;
        } elseif ( $j > 1 && $i == $number_question ) {
         echo "<button id='".$j."' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>
                           <button id='".$j."' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>";
         echo "</div>";
         $i = 0;
         $j++;
        }
        
        }
         $k++;
          } ?> 
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');
include('db_connection.php');
$stu_id=$_SESSION['sid'];
echo $gender=$_POST['stu_ans'];
echo $que=$_POST['q_id'];
$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question where id='$que'");
$ro=mysqli_fetch_array($q);
//$que=$ro['id'];
$date=date('d/m/y');
$right_ans=$ro['right_ans'];
////////////////////////Ajax Data Saved//////////////////////////////

$q1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student_ans where  q_id='$que' AND stu_id='$stu_id'");
$ro1=mysqli_num_rows($q1);
if($ro1==''){
 $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO student_ans(stu_ans,q_id,stu_id,date,right_ans) value('$gender','$que','$stu_id','$date','$right_ans')");
}else{

$sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"update student_ans set stu_ans='$gender' where q_id='$que' AND stu_id='$stu_id'"); 

}
?>
```

This code working like when i am click radio button so ajax fuction working and save the answer into database but i want that when inserting answer into database with answer insert Question ID

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: no error get..but i want that when radio button click answer and question insert automatic insert into database by ajax

Comment: Change `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){  ` to `$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){  `